# wpf animation to hide and collapse panel on button click

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I have a StackPanel and a button. Initallty the button content should be << When the button is clicked the StackPanel content should collapse and the button text should become >> where collapse is happening correctly. Again when the same button is pressed I want the content to show up and text should be << which I am unsure how to do.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" x:Name="stkEasyLocatePanel" Loaded="stkEasyLocatePanel_Loaded" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,28"></StackPanel>

    <Button Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" Panel.ZIndex="140" Height="20" Width="25" Background="Transparent" Content="&lt;&lt;">
         <Button.Triggers>
             <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                 <BeginStoryboard>
                     <Storyboard x:Name="HideStackPanel">
                         <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="stkEasyLocatePanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="330" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3">
                             <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                 <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn"></PowerEase>
                             </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                         </DoubleAnimation>
                     </Storyboard>
                 </BeginStoryboard>
                 <BeginStoryboard>
                     <!--This part dosent work. The content collapses and shows on a single click. But I want it to happen on two clicks of same button-->
                     <Storyboard x:Name="ShowStackPanel"> 
                         <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="stkEasyLocatePanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="330" Duration="0:0:0.3">
                             <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                 <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn"></PowerEase>
                             </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                         </DoubleAnimation>
                     </Storyboard>
                 </BeginStoryboard>                                  
             </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Do you want it in pure xaml, and would you prefer using Triggers or VisualStateManager?

Comment: Either of them is fine. But I would like to know the solution to do this for a normal button.

Comment: Why does a normal button matter? You could style a Toggle to mimic the design/behavior of a normal button if necessary and @AnjumSKhan answer is a correct option. To use just normal button you would need to handle a conditional expression in code behind, the pure xaml approach is just fine in this instance in my opinion.

Comment: Oh Got it. Yes toggle button works fine. I was wondering if there was a way to solve the problem with a normal button using pure xaml. But if it involves code behind then I guess Toggle Button is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Button` with `ToggleButton` , and use code below as it is, and see if this solves your problem.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Width="330" x:Name="stkEasyLocatePanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,28">
            <Image Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" Panel.ZIndex="140" Height="20" Width="25" Background="Transparent" Content="&lt;&lt;">
            <ToggleButton.Triggers>               
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="HideStackPanel">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="stkEasyLocatePanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="330" Duration="0:0:0.3">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn"></PowerEase>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="&lt;&lt;"  />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                        <!--This part dosent work. The content collapses and shows on a single click. But I want it to happen on two clicks of same button-->
                        <Storyboard x:Name="ShowStackPanel">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="stkEasyLocatePanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="330" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn"></PowerEase>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="&gt;&gt;"  />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ToggleButton.Triggers>
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks thats what I did. I thought of posting the same code as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to keep a variable in code behind (something like `isCollaped`) and then in code behind hookup to the click event of the button. Inside the click method of the button place some logic to hide or show the stack panel.
For example:

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" x:Name="stkEasyLocatePanel" Loaded="stkEasyLocatePanel_Loaded" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,28"></StackPanel>

//Add the Click event.
<Button Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" Panel.ZIndex="140" Height="20" Width="25" Background="Transparent" Content="&lt;&lt;" Click=Button_Click>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
bool isCollapsed = false;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (isCollapsed)
    {
        //Create and run show Stackpanel animation
        //Change the content of the button to "<<"
    }
    else
    {
        //Create and run hide Stackpanel animation
        //Change the content of the button to ">>"
    }
    isCollapsed = !isCollapsed;
}
```

**EDIT**

As requested in the comment, this is an example on how you would animate from code behind.

```
if (isCollapsed)
{
    DoubleAnimation showAnim = new DoubleAnimation();
    showAnim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3);
    showAnim.EasingFunction = new PowerEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn };
    showAnim.From = 330;
    showAnim.To = 0;
    stkEasyLocatePanel.BeginAnimation(StackPanel.WidthProperty, showAnim);
    //Change the content of the button to "<<"
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you don't know how to do animations from code behind, so I can give you an example.

Comment: Hi Agustin I used a Togglebutton and it works just like a normal button but it has both checked and unchecked events where you can perform animations in xaml.. Il post my code if it proves helpful to someone. But could you post the code how to animate from code behind it would be definitely helpful.

Comment: And if you use the toggle button, then you can still hookup to the Click event, and instead of using an `isCollapsed` variable you can just check for your `ToggleButton` `IsChecked` property (this is, in case you still want to try code behind).

Comment: Thanks for the help Agustin. This should be helpful as a reference.